# How to make a stacked bar chart from two sets of grouped data (Google Sheets)?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns of data: country and gender. I want to make a stacked bar chart by gender with countries on the x-axis (i.e. how many of each gender from each country). How can I do this in Google Sheets? Is there a way to do it without reformatting the data (if not, is there a trivial way to reformat it?)

I can create the bar chart with the aggregate for the count by country, but there doesn't seem to be a way to group by the identifier in another column.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. You have two columns; one is gender, but you want to create a chart showing the "how many of **each** gender - doesn't that require two "Gender" columns (one for "Female" and one for "Male". Would you please edit your question to include some sample data and an example of a successful outcome. The chart outcome might simply be a drawing but it is not clear from your question what appearance this chart should have.